# As3 Trigonometry and math

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, trigonometry

i'm trying to create a minigame with circles rotating around circles
however, i have a problem when i shoot the circle and it hits the second circle it doesnt continue the angle but "jumping" to the other side i'm sure it something with the angle var that should reset or something. can you help me im getting nervous around here... :(
[check the example](http://www.taktitech.com/images/CirclesJump.swf)

This is my code for the enter frame function that deals with the circles

```
public function UpdateCircles(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < EnemySpriteVector.length; i++) 
        {
            EnemySpriteVector[i].rotation += EnemySpriteVector[i].enemyspeed;
        }

        var rad:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180); // Converting Degrees To Radians
        if (IsplayerShoot)
        {
            playerSprite.x += Math.cos(rad) * PlayerCircleShootSpeed;  
            playerSprite.y += Math.sin(rad) * PlayerCircleShootSpeed; 

            for (var j:int = 0; j < EnemySpriteVector.length; j++) 
            {
                if (EnemySpriteVector[j].hitTestPoint(playerSprite.x,playerSprite.y) && (EnemySpriteVector[j].IsCircleHit == false))
                {
                    trace("hit");
                    EnemySpriteVector[j].IsCircleHit = true;
                    removeChild(EnemySpriteVector[0]);
                    EnemySpriteVector.splice(0, 1);

                    var EnemySprite:Sprite = new EnemySpriteClass();
                    EnemySpriteVector.push(EnemySprite);
                    addChild(EnemySprite);
                    EnemySprite.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    EnemySprite.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                    IsplayerShoot = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            playerSprite.x = EnemySpriteVector[0].x + EnemySpriteVector[0].radius * Math.cos(rad); // Position The Orbiter Along x-axis
            playerSprite.y = EnemySpriteVector[0].y + EnemySpriteVector[0].radius * Math.sin(rad); // Position The Orbiter Along y-axis
            angle += EnemySpriteVector[0].enemyspeed; // Object will orbit clockwise
            playerSprite.rotation = (Math.atan2(playerSprite.y - EnemySpriteVector[0].y, playerSprite.x - EnemySpriteVector[0].x) * 180 / Math.PI); //only rotates the player circle itself
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when the **pink** circle hits the **green** one it simply continues its rotation from where it left of. A quick solution would be to **add 180 degrees** to the angle. Keep in mind this will only work for static objects. If you want a more dynamic environment I would recommend using vectors *(linear algebra)*. Vector math is really easy to understand and it hides a lot of complex trigonometry. [You can start here](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) :)

Comment: Thanks,Where should i add 180 and how,
Do you mean to add to the angle var 180 or to convert it to rad?
Thanks again :)

Comment: Well from the code above it looks like **angle** is defined else where, so I'm guessing it's continuing from where it left of. On hit you should add 180° to it, and that work because angle will wrap around _(540° = 180°)_. If you prefer radians, then simply add PI.

Comment: Amazing! it's working,
all iv'e done is on the hit, angle+=180;
Thank you very much!